# How do I grab variable from a R for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm using R to try to run a model.

I have a for loop and I want to grab a variable, check it, and if true, change the value of another column in that same row.  Something like this

```
    for(i in Traffic){
      if(Traffic$accident == "yes"){
      Traffic[i]$result == "crash"
      }
    }
```

But I get this error

Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i) : undefined columns selected

The columns exists. Not sure why it won't work.

Comment: `Traffic[i]` is the `i`th column of the `Traffic` data set. I think you want `Traffic$result[i]` or `Traffic[i, "result"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R is vectorized, you can generally replace `for` loops with a single statement or a function from the apply family.  In your case:

```
Traffic$result <- ifelse(Traffic$accident == "yes", "crash", "nothing")
```

Will process the entire data frame.  Note that a new `Traffic$result` column will be created if it does not already exist.